# Getting count of groupings in R - throws error - not a vector?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame with a head that looks like this:

```
> head(movies_by_yr)

Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: YR_Released [6]

               Movie_Title YR_Released Rating Num_Reviews
                <fctr>      <fctr>  <dbl>       <int>
1 The Shawshank Redemption        1994    9.2     1773755
2            The Godfather        1972    9.2     1211083
3   The Godfather: Part II        1974    9.0      832342
4          The Dark Knight        2008    8.9     1755341
5             12 Angry Men        1957    8.9      477276
6         Schindler's List        1993    8.9      909358
```

Note that when created, I specified `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, so I believe the columns that got converted to factors were converted when I grouped the data frame in preparation for the next step:

```
movies_by_yr <- group_by(problem1_data, YR_Released)
```

Now we come to the problem.  The goal is to group by YR_Released so we can get counts of records by year.  I thought the next step would be something like this, but it throws an error and I am not sure what i am doing wrong:

```
summarise(movies_by_yr, total = nrow(YR_Released))
```

I choose `nrow` because once you have a grouping, the number of rows within that grouping should be the count.  Can someone point me to what I am doing wrong?

The error thrown is:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Not a vector
```

But I know this data.frame was created from a series of vectors and whatever is different from the sample code from class and my attempt, I am just not seeing it.  Hoping someone can answer this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use data that everyone has, like the built-in `mtcars` data.frame, to make this more useful for future readers.

If you look at the documentation `?nrow` you'll see that function is meant to be called on a data.frame or matrix.  You are calling it on a column, `YR_Released`.  There is a vector-specific variant of the function `nrow`, called (confusingly) `NROW` - if you try that instead, it may work.

But even if it does, the intended dplyr way to count rows is with `n()`, like this:

```
mycars <- mtcars
mycars <- group_by(mycars, cyl)
summarise(mycars, total = NROW(cyl))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl total
#>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1     4    11
#> 2     6     7
#> 3     8    14
```

And because it's such a common use case, the wrapper function `count()` will save you some code:

```
mtcars %>%
  count(cyl)
```

Comment: count() is not working in the context of my original code which is a data frame.  Following your model, tried: my_df %>% count(my_column) and it threw a slew of errors.  I do not know why.  It looks like an elegenat solution.  Your earlier solution which is what the problem asks for - works, but now I'm grappling with how to sort it or extract just the max values from the counts.  Thanks for getting me this far.  Very helpful.

Comment: Problem actually wanted the years with the highest count.  Thanks to you - I just got there.  Once I set up my code to model your first answer, it was then a simple matter of storing in a data frame and indexing for rows equivelent to max value of the count column ... my code looked like this:  movies_by_yr <- group_by(problem1_data, YR_Released);
df_sum1 <- tbl_df(summarise(movies_by_yr, rCount = NROW(YR_Released)));
df_sum1[df_sum1$rCount == max(df_sum1$rCount),];

Comment: I think `count()` takes a string argument. This works: `mtcars %>% count("cyl")` or `mtcars %>% summarize(count(cyl))` but the later leaves ugly column names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I think it's what you want)

```
table(movies_by_year$YR_Released)
```

Comment: once I correct "movies_by_year" to "movies_by_yr" to match my original code, this does return a correct answer to the problem, so thanks.  If this was a real world problem, I'd be done, but I believe I am supposed to use group_by and summarise like in the training exercise we did in class.  Any insight as to how to fix the original approach (even though it may not be the best one) ?